# grep with wc -l caching the count

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, ubuntu-16.04

I noticed when doing a row count using below command multiple times cached results is shown, any ideas why?

```
grep "xxx" "filename.log" | wc -l
```

This returns the count value when run first time, If run again it still gives the same count value, even though the file has more matching values.

what could be the reason.

PS - I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Update - `grep -c "xxx" filename.log` is returning the correct count. Still wondering why the command above don't give updated result.

How to ensure the buffers are written to file at regular intervals?

FYI - I am checking this on a nginx access log file, which is continously being updated with the request calls, with average write speed of `10 lines/sec.`

Comment: is your file getting updated dynamically while matching the count?

Comment: yes it is updated dynamically. I thought about buffer being the root cause, but even after 24 hours still same .

Comment: I don't have your answer, but my first step would be to try `grep -c xxx filename.log` instead. I'm assuming you are already 100% sure that the new lines have indeed already been added to the file - not just passed to some running program's "print" function and waiting in its I/O buffer.

Comment: grep -c is returning the correct count, what would be the reason for  would wc -l to not return ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a sequence of characters that doesn't end with a newline isn't a line, according to the POSIX specification. `grep -c` apparently takes more latitude in deciding what constitutes a line than `wc -l` can. This would only explain a discrepancy of 1, though, as your file can't have more than one "line" that doesn't end with a newline.

Comment: so you mean to say some of the lines are not ending with new line character? It doesnt seem to be correct as the nginx log file is pretty standard logging file, and it  is already finding 8million+ count with wc -l, but whereas the file as more than 15million+ lines now.

Comment: @chepner At least GNU grep ends each line with a newline, even if it was missing (see [my comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062140/grep-with-wc-l-caching-the-count/51062265#comment89114609_51062265)). Perhaps the logic behind this is that `grep` actually outputs records (with an optional file path) rather than lines directly.

Answer (score 1):

If your new `xxx` occurrences are on the same lines as the old ones, that's OK because `grep` outputs whole lines by default. You can use `grep -o` to output individual matches on separate lines. By the way, `grep -c` (or `grep -o -c`) can be used for counting (which is faster since it involves less writing).

However, if you don't see new lines in your file after you think they are written (which can be continuously checked with `tail -f` or with `less`: press `F` to read new data and `Ctrl-C` to stop reading), the likely reason is buffering. (Regarding your comment on 24 hours: note that buffers don't flush simply over time but only they are overflown or explicitly flushed.) You can try to call `stdbuf -o0 program ...` instead of `program ...`.

Comment: @mdeora And `grep ... | wc -l` doesn't?

Comment: its giving old count, which was given when i had run yesterday on the file. whereas  grep -c "xxx" filename.log is giving upto date count. I have updated my question.

Comment: @mdeora That's curious. I've just tested: even when file contents doesn't end with `\n`, both `grep ... | wc -l` and `grep -c` behave as if it does. What about `grep ... | tail`? Does it show up-to-date lines?

Comment: yes it was a bit strange thats why i posted it, let me check that too.

Comment: grep ... | tail  is working fine and updating the count.